# installing libssl0.9.8 on debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, libssl

I'm trying to install uTorrent on debian 7 but every time I tried to run it got this error message :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I think that it no longer available on debian repository. I've tried to make some symlink to solve the problem, but again get the same message. how can I solve this problem?

Comment: great, I had problem with vmware-diskmanager, now work fine with this solutions. In my case error was SSLLoadSharedLibrary: Failed to load library libcrypto.so.0.9.8:/usr/bin/libdir/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
Core dump limit is 0 KB.
Child process 1452 failed to dump core (status 0x6). thanks P.D In Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits

Answer (score 14):

There is a package for amd64

```
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20110406T213352Z/pool/main/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_amd64.deb
```

and then install it:

```
root@07:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d# dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libssl0.9.8.
(Reading database ... 120511 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libssl0.9.8 (from libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up libssl0.9.8 (0.9.8o-7) ...

root@07:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d# php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2013 07:56:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend Debugger v5.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2010, by Zend Technologies
root@07:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d#
```

Comment: I got the same message when i'm trying install Erlang and Elixir on Deepin Linux. I installed this and works for me.

Answer (score 4):

On Debian 7 you can find only libssl1.0.0, but libssl0.9.8 is part of debian 6 (squeeze). You can get the packet from [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/libssl0.9.8/download) and manually install it with a command like

```
dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-4squeeze14_i386.deb
```

For 64 bits architecture, you need the 32 bits libc and zlib1g binaries before installing it, because utorrent binaries are actually available for 32 bits only. In order to add them you need to add i386 architecture `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, add [arch=amd64,i386] to repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list. For details, see http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO. You then need to run `apt-get update; apt-get install libc6:i386 zlib1g:i386`

Comment: I've installed it but got another error :  error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: You need the 32 bits one, apparently you've installed the 64 bits one. Uninstall it and download this one http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/libssl0.9.8/download

Comment: I've downloaded it but when I tried to install it I got an architectural error...

Comment: Please be more specific on what your problem is. I have tested the manual installation with dpkg and it worked for me. Please detail on what you were trying to do specifically and the error you obtained. Did you try to start utserver (this is what i've tried), or what were you trying to do exactly? Do you have a 32 or 64 bit installation? Try running uname -a and uname -m and provide the ouput.

Comment: it's uname output : Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I've updated my main comment on what needs to be done in case you have a 64 bits installation

Comment: [here is the 64bit version](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/libssl0.9.8/download)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same issue playing with gitlab. You can try to get libssl.so.0.9.8:

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20110406T213352Z/pool/main/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_i386.deb
```

and then to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 12.04 and installing this fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```